# Il l'a accusé DU ou DE harcèlement psychologique

Tags: grammaire, articles

Est-ce qu'on dit :

> Il l'a accusé **du** harcèlement psychologique.

ou

> Il l'a accusé **de** harcèlement psychologique.

Je dirais *du* parce que c'est *le* harcèlement psychologique et donc on a *accuser de* + *le* = *accuser du* mais je n'en suis pas sûre...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles.

Soit il y a plusieurs chefs d'accusation dont l'un est un cas de harcèlement psychologique et la forme avec *du* est possible (mais très improbable ici).

Soit il s'agit de harcèlement psychologique en général et il faut utiliser *de*, la forme correcte étant donc :

> Il l'a accusé **de** harcèlement psychologique.

Voici des exemples montrant la différence entre *du* et *de* :

> On l'a accusé **du** vol du porte-feuille du plaignant. [le vol de quelque chose de précis]
>
> On l'a accusé **de** vol à la tire. [un vol, sans autre précision]

Comment: Si lmc est anglo-saxonne, je crois que cette différence est // à celle que l'on peut trouver entre *accused **with*** et *accused **for***.

Comment: « Il l'a accusé *du* harcèlement psychologique *de* sa femme » … déplacement du *de* rattaché à la cible — Étrange courbe https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=du+harc%C3%A8lement&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdu%20harc%C3%A8lement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdu%20harc%C3%A8lement%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Fólkvangr — C’est la formule que j’emploierais naturellement, mais en gardant la structure de la question, le *du* devient comminatoire dans la bouche d’un procureur « Il (le procureur) l’a accusé du harcèlement de cette femme », on passe du constat d’un fait à l’énonciation d’un acte juridique ; le *du* n’est pas interdit comme réponse à la question

Comment: @Fólkvangr J'ai écrit que la forme avec *du* était très improbable et que la forme correcte est celle avec *de*. Il n'empêche qu'une phrase comme « ***On l'a accusé du meurtre.*** » ne pose pas de problème grammatical et je ne vois donc pas de raison de rejeter « ***il l'a accusé du harcèlement psychologique.*** »

Answer (score 3):

La différence entre *du* et  *de* qui se constate avec les compléments masculins après le verbe *accuser de* est également possible avec les compléments féminins et pluriels.

Différence entre *de la* et *de*:

> *On l'a accusé **de la** destruction des dossiers.* [*tous les dossiers*]
>
> *On l’a accusé **de** destruction involontaire de dossiers* [*certains dossiers*]

Différence entre *des* et *de*:

> *On l’a accusé **des** vols signalés dans le quartier.* [*tous les vols*]
>
> *On l’a accusé **de** vols à l’étalage dans des magasins huppés.* [*certains vols*]

La question rentre dans le sujet plus général de la différence entre ***de*** avec article et ***de*** sans article.

Answer (score -2):

Il s'agit ici d'un *h* aspiré -c'est donc dire d'une consonne. 
Il faut alors dire LE harcèlement est illégal. Il est accusé DE harcèlement. 
DU harcèlement n'est donc pas approprié.

Comment: Je ne vois pas pourquoi le *h* aspiré implique *de* plutôt que *du*.